# how a django application can interact with users/clients local device filesystem?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, filesystems

I have made an application using django which has a feature to download the youtube videos and I have hosted it on heroku. By default, the contents that the user downloads gets stored in the heroku cloud where application files resides.But i want those contents to get downloaded in user's local file system.

here is the code which downloads the fetched video in the downloads folder of heroku cloud,but i want it to download the video and store it in user's local filesystem

```
import pytube
import os  
import sys  
from pathlib import Path  
from pytube import YouTube  
path_to_download_folder = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), "Downloads")  
yt=YouTube(sys.argv[1])  
stream=yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()   
stream.download(output_path=path_to_download_folder)`
```

how can i do so? pls help

Comment: Hello, when asking a question try to respect these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, provide a code snippet of what you have done so that it is easier for everyone to help you!

Comment: sure sir...will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that the video is downloaded in Downloads folder in Heroku Cloud. Then you can do the following

- Get the path of the downloaded file from Heroku
- Put a `<a href="your file path goes here...">` for the user to download the video on his machine.